# SailsJS - SQL queries and Data Access Objects

Tags: node.js

I just recently started to learn NodeJS/SailsJS and have few questions.
Please, note that I have strong Java background ( this affects my style of thinking and the architecture ).

1. How to prevent SQL injection in SailsJS?
   Basically, I have:

   User.query(query, function(err, result) {
     if (err)
       return next(err);
     //
     res.json({ data : stepsCount });
   });
   But where/how should I put parameters for SQL query?
   In Java I used to make something like:

   Query q = new Query("select * from User where id = :id");
   q.setParameter("id", some-value);
2. What about Data Access Object?
   I am feeling uncomfortable having SQL queries in Controller.
   Do you have any best practices for that? Maybe some example projects?
   All example projects I've found so far do not use some complex SQL queries.
   They are more like school projects using some predefined methonds in Domain classes ( like User.create, User.find ) etc.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Maksim

Answer (score 0):

Sailsjs use a DAO library written in javascript (of course). it is called   [waterlinejs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) The documentation is [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs)

Basically, it means, if you want to find User with specific id, you only need

```
User.findOne({id:xxx}).then(function(data){
    res.json(data);
})
```

This is like the main advantage of using sailsjs, because waterlinejs can have different adapters, but all of them can construct User model, and access them like this. So if you use sails-mysql-adapter, then it will create a user table, with id, name...etc as column, if you use memory adapter, it will be stored in memory.

It does provide User.query('select.....',callback) in case what  you want cannot be achieved by this DAO methods. But because it is for last resort, for query building, sailsjs does not have native support, you can certainly use package like [sprintf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js) to build sql.

Since you are a java programmer, (just like me), as a side note, I'd like you to remember these findOne() methods provided by waterlinejs are asynchronous, and also in a [promise](http://www.toptal.com/javascript/javascript-promises) manner. They are quite different from java. I spent a lot of time wrap my head around this, but as soon as I am comfortable with this idea, I start to love it right away.

Let me know if this is clear.